Add additional Java libraries to the spring boot container
Since some libraries contain licenses that do not allow distribution, customers who want to run our software must get the libraries by themselves and add these to the spring boot application.
Previously, we added the spring boot uber jar to a container and used the PropertiesLauncher and the LOADER_PATH so that the customer can mount the library in the container and adapt the classpath.
Now that we want to switch for the image generation to buildpack, just like mvn spring-boot:build-image would do. As the application is unpacked in the image, it seems to me that the PropertiesLauncher and LOADER_PATH would no longer work.
What is the recommended way to add third party Java libraries to a buildback-built spring boot container?

must get the libraries by themselves and add these to the spring boot application. -> Specifically how are you having them do this now, without buildpacks? How do they get files into the container image? Sounds like a volume mount, but want to make sure.

Exactly, the necessary libraries are mounted into the container and referenced using the LOADER_PATH environment variable.

Turns out the configuration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin was wrong. The configuration <layout>ZIP<layout> was only active for the repackage goal, but not for the build-image goal.
After correctly configuring <layout>ZIP<layout> for the build-image goal, the generated buildpack-image uses the org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.PropertiesLauncher which allows again the use of the LOADER_PATH.
To clarify, this was my wrong configuration:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.spring-boot}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
                <classifier>app</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

The fixed configuration, where the layout (and also the classifier) is always present regardless of the actual spring-boot-maven-plugin goal:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.spring-boot}</version>
    <configuration>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
        <classifier>app</classifier>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


I'm not sure I'd say the plugin is wrong, because the default behavior is such that it should not put the built JAR file into the container, it should put the exploded JAR into the build container. That's working as designed. There are speed advantages to using the exploded JAR. Buildpacks are flexible though and should work with both, so this sounds like the perfect fix for your particular use case.

I didn't want to say the actual plugin would be wrong but the actual configuration of the plugin in my pom. I added some maven snippets to clarify this.
